# PDF get an .html file extenssions when saved in mac

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I am having a CakePHP application where I use tcpdf for generating my PDFs, but whenever the pdf is saved into a mac computer, it gets a .html extenssion and cannot be opened until the extenssion is deleted.
But it only happens on mac, if I use safari on windows, the file is downloaded in .pdf.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting the mime type to "application/pdf"? If you did not do that your mac might add the extension because the mime type might be "text/html", while it doesn't have an extension that matches with that type. Why safari on windows does not do that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes the type is set to pdf, but that does not solve the problem.